# What does the CLI means in PowerCLI?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, powercli

PowerCLI is a scripting tool used for VM automation and creation.

Is there a way to use this scrip to automate and create VM?

May I also know what is silent installation and how does it work?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CLI = Command Line Interface

I.e. a prompt you can type in commands textually as opposed to a visual point & click UI.

Comment: is it Command Line Interface? Btw thanks for your swift response. =)